# Socket.IO disconnect event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, socket.io

My code is working fine when new user joins but when a user left it doesn't show anything
Can anyone tell me error in my code

Here is my server side code

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server); // socketio expects to be called by raw http server so we did little bit of refactoring

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

// let count = 0;

// server(emit) -> client(receive) -> countUpdated
// client(emit) -> server(receive) -> increment
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New web socket connection");

  socket.emit("message", "Welcome!");
  socket.broadcast.emit("message", "A new user has joined"); // it emits msg to everyone except the user who run this command

  socket.on("sendMessage", (message) => {
    io.emit("message", message);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      io.emit("message", "A user has left");
    }); // when user disconnect we use socket.on("disconnect")
  });
```

Here is my client side code

```
const socket = io(); // to communicate with socketio we did this, now we can send events or recieve events from clients

socket.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(message);
});

const form = document.querySelector("#message-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let message = e.target.elements.message.value; // e.target refers to form and we can select elements of form using the name property we defined in html
  socket.emit("sendMessage", message);
});
```

I am expecting when a user left
It should show "A user has left" in console

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have only start to listen to `disconnect` event when the client has already sent at least 1 message. Here's the relevant extract:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // …

  socket.on("sendMessage", (message) => {
    // …

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {

    });
  });
});
```

You should therefore reduce the callback nesting, and start listening to `disconnect` in the `connection` handler directly. Which leads to:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New web socket connection");

  socket.emit("message", "Welcome!");
  socket.broadcast.emit("message", "A new user has joined"); // it emits msg to everyone except the user who run this command

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    io.emit("message", "A user has left");
  }); // when user disconnect we use socket.on("disconnect")

  socket.on("sendMessage", (message) => {
    io.emit("message", message);
  });
});
```